# AWS unencrypted SNS Topic SCP policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-scp

can anyone help with the format to create an scp policy in json format to restrict the creation of any unencrypted sns topics? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon SNS - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsns.html) only lists Tags as the available Conditions for the `CreateTopic` command.